# creating a timer for a c# wrapper class

Tags: c#, .net, timer, outlook

I have a wrapper class in Outlook that has the potential to handle a large number of events at one time, but I only want to prompt the user one time after it fires.  I'm using Redemption to store my message/folder IDs, but need to create a way to fire the event after all the IDs have been captured.

It's been recommended that I use a Timer class to handle this, but I haven't written one yet and am a little confused on how to properly accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example gleaned [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class TimerExample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Timer aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        Console.ReadLine(); // artificially pause app to let timer run
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer event fired");
                    // pseudocode:
                    // check for new events collected
                    // if any exist, take first and present UI to user
                    // if more exist, then consinue
    }
}
```

This is a console app that creates and starts the timer in the app's entry point. If you're doing a GUI app then the same code could used in an OnLoad event in a Form. The OnTimedEvent handler would remain pretty much the same. That event is where you would out your logic to test for OUtlook events collected and decide whether or not the user needs to be notified.

Comment: I've seen this, but am not sure how to trigger this inside a wrapper class when multiple threads are going to be kicked off simultaneously

Comment: What does your wrapper class wrap? Btw, this version of the Timer idea uses threading... Start it and handle the events where it makes sense. What are your different threads responsible for?

Comment: It's wrapping the MoveTo and CopyTo events in Outlook that are captured by Redemption.